# How can you add a header to a specific request in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I've got a test fragment that makes a few requests, which work fine. I now want to add a new PUT request that uploads a file to a an azure storage account container. I currently get a 400 with an error that a mandatory header hasn't been included. After a little research it appears I need the 'x-ms-blob-type' header with a value of 'BlockBlob'.

This is where my issue lies. I've added an HTTP Header Manager to that particular request, but the header doesn't seem to get added. There is a Header Manager at the fragment level, that is used to apply generic headers to all requests, but this header manager is just for that request. I was expecting the 2 to be merged, but it looks like no headers are being applied to that particular request.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is correct, HTTP Header Managers obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) and top-level headers are being recursively merged to the local HTTP Header Managers.

[image]

So try looking at Request -> Request Headers tab of the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and see what headers are being sent

Additionally you can [enable debug logging for JMeter's HTTP components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and upon JMeter restart you should see the outgoing headers in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out it was applying that particular header, but missing another one. This helped to figure that out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add header manager at request level as JMeter gives preference to the request level header manger even it is present at test plan level.

For reference see the attached snapshots.

[image: Configure header manager at request level - a]

[image: Configure header manager at request level - b]

Comment: Thanks, but this was already explained in the accepted answer.